# keeping outer view unchanged while just reloading inner view in angular-ui

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have few templates somewhat like these:

home.html

```
<div ui-view></div>   <!-- homeframe.html plugs in here -->
```

homeframe.html

```
<!-- quickcontact.html and settings.html plugs in here -->
<div ui-view="widget"></div>

<a class="link" ng-click="changeUrl('/')">quickcontact</a>
<a class="link" ng-click="changeUrl('/settings')">settings</a>
```

quickcontact.html

```
<div>
.
.
.
</div>
```

settings.html

```
<div>
.
.
.
</div>
```

`homeframe.html` loads inside the `ui-view` appearing in `home.html`. Again, `quickcontact.html` and `settings.html` loads inside `widget ui-view`. I want to keep the `homeframe.html` from reloading again and just keep changing the content of `widget ui-view`. How can I achieve this using angular-ui states?

Answer (score 1):

Try navigating to your quickcontact or settings states directly, instead of changing the url to trigger them. You can use ui-router's [ui-sref](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref) directive to trigger state transitions. Assuming the states are named `settings` and `quickcontact`:

```
<a class="link" ui-sref="quickcontact">quickcontact</a>
<a class="link" ui-sref="settings">settings</a>
```